# How to test for exceptions and a return value from a lambda expression in an NUnit Assert.That clause

Tags: c#, .net, nunit

I'm performing a simple NUnit test, and want to confirm there is no exceptions in my method. However, this method will return something: and I want to test on the returned value **as well**.

Here is my existing code which tests for exceptions (this works!):

```
// This works
[Test]
public void AbleToGetTheDatabaseNames()
{
    Assert.That( () => GetTheDatabaseNames(), Throws.Nothing);
}
private List<string> GetTheDatabaseNames()
{
    var mySql = new MySqlDb();
    return mySql.GetDatabaseNames();
}
```

However, in the lambda expression `() => GetTheDatabaseNames()` how do I get at the returned value, so I can then go ahead and test the returned List of strings?

```
// This doesn't work
[Test]
public void AbleToGetTheDatabaseNames()
{
    Assert.That( () => GetTheDatabaseNames(), Throws.Nothing);
    Assert.That( retVal, Has.Count.EqualTo(1));
}
private List<string> GetTheDatabaseNames()
{
    var mySql = new MySqlDb();
    return mySql.GetDatabaseNames();
}
```

How do I get `retVal` from the lambda expression so I can get at the returned `List<string>`? Is it even possible to do it here? If not, what would be the recommended pattern - should I call `GetTheDatabaseNames()` twice (which would seem superfluous) ?

Comment: I dunno much about the `Assert.That()` syntax, never liked it; but you can always just `try{ CollectionAssert.AreEqual(new [] {"a"}, new MysqlDb(). GetTheDatabaseNames()); } catch(Exception e) { Assert.Fail(e.Message); }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just invoke the member under test and get the returned value. If no error is thrown the code will flow to completion. No need to assert no error is thrown. A thrown error should fail the test

```
[Test]
public void AbleToGetTheDatabaseNames() {
    //Arrange
    var mySql = new MySqlDb();

    //Act
    List<string> retVal = mySql.GetDatabaseNames();

    //Assert
    Assert.That(retVal, Has.Count.EqualTo(1));
}
```

Another way is to capture the result in the lambda expression and pass it on to the next assertion.

```
[Test]
public void AbleToGetTheDatabaseNames() {
    //Arrange
    List<string> retVal = null;

    //Act
    Action act = () => retVal = new MySqlDb.GetDatabaseNames();

    //Assert
    Assert.That(act, Throws.Nothing);
    Assert.That(retVal, Has.Count.EqualTo(1));
}
```

Comment: Thank-you, I have investigated both your solutions in detail for my particular scenario. NUnit tells me that the test has failed. I also love the 2nd solution, however they both seem to be equivalent in my case so I have adopted your first solution's approach.

Comment: Upon even *more* investigation @Nkosi, I have decided to adopt the second approach.